# Initializing pointer to an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char *arr[100];
```

How do I correctly initialize this? Is there any other problem with this line? I'm new to C and programming in general and am having a difficult time understanding this.

This is the rest of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main ()
{
   char ans[100];
   int count;
   count=0;
   char *arr[100];
   char *srtarr[100];
   while(count<100)
   {
      if(strcmp(ans,"done\n")!=0)  
      {               
         printf("Enter names when done type done:");
         fgets(ans,100,stdin);
         arr[count]=strdup(ans);
      }
      printf("%s",arr[count]);
      count++;

   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: the program is crashing and im pretty sure it has to do with the pointer array

Comment: The array is not initialized statically in your program.  My answer follows.

Answer (score 1):

The program is crashing since you have a logic error.

Take a look at your while loop.

```
while(count<100)
{
   if(strcmp(ans,"done\n")!=0)  
   {               
      printf("Enter names when done type done:");
      fgets(ans,100,stdin);
      arr[count]=strdup(ans);
   }
   printf("%s",arr[count]);
   count++;
}
```

Let's say the user entered

```
done
```

as the first line of input. Nothing gets set to `arr[1]`. At that time, `arr[1]` is not initialized. It points to garbage. That would lead to undefined behavior in the line

```
   printf("%s",arr[count]);
```

You need a little rearrangement of the `while` loop.

```
while(count<100)
{
   printf("Enter names when done type done:");
   fgets(ans,100,stdin);
   if(strcmp(ans,"done\n") ==0 )  
   {               
      break;
   }

   arr[count]=strdup(ans);
   printf("%s",arr[count]);
   count++;
}
```

Comment: @thomas, yes. If don't want that to happen, you'll have to move the two lines above `count++` to above the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     arr[i] = NULL;
}
```

or a clever way:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
```

The clever way just writes 0 to all your elements at once.

Comment: so just to make sure i understand it i need to put a 0 in each element of the array?

Comment: Yes, 0 is the special pointer value that says "this points to nothing".  Although strictly speaking it is actually NULL, which is 0 cast to a void pointer.

Comment: These are both worse than `char *arr[100] = {0};`.  However, no initialization is required at all . Also, on some systems, the `memset` version does not generate null pointers.